# Multisite behind Varnish

Tags: multisite, server, configuration

I'm trying to use varnish with a wp 3.0.5 site with Network (Multisite), when I access the varnish URL, I get this message:

```
Multisite only works without the port number in the URL.
```

Do I need a custom VCL to make this work? I'm using the same backend config for other wordpress sites that work fine..

If I need to ask this on serverfault, let me know and I'll ask there.

Comment: I smell that this is very much related to wordpress, would be cool to find out more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15936

You basically need to modify wp-includes/ms-settings.php like this (remove '-' lines; add the '+' line):

```
@@ -26,18 +26,8 @@
  if ( !isset( $current_site ) || !isset( $current_blog ) ) {
+        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = preg_replace( '|:\d+$|', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
         $domain = addslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
-        if ( false !== strpos( $domain, ':' ) ) {
-               ....
-                        wp_die( /*WP_I18N_NO_PORT_NUMBER*/'Multisite only works without the port number in the URL.'/*/WP_I18N_NO_PORT_NUMBER*/ );
-                }
-        }
```

Comment: thank you. that worked.. is there something I can do to have it so that this gets into trunk/3.1/3.0.6?

Answer (score 3):

that Wordpress error message is probably misleading.

Wordpress looks for the domain name in [`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` (PHP Manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and if it contains a port number (separated with : as usual like http://example.com:444/) it will only accept two variants: port 80 an port 443.

I assume that in your varnish configuration other ports are given and so you bump into that one.

I'm no expert with varnish, but that's where I would start to tinker with. First of all I would output that value. File in question is `/wp-includes/ms-settings.php`, ~ line 38. You can start adding a `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);` before the wp_die statement.